Strange partial freeze or disconnection (how to find the cause?)
I have a Raspberry Pi functioning as a server for various tasks, including granting access to a port via RFID, managing a Telegram bot, and serving as a bridge to access my network via SSH from the outside. It also features a graphical interface for managing some of these services, which I access using VNC.
Strangely, this Raspberry Pi occasionally becomes unreachable:
First I notice the Telegram bot stops responding (or someone calls me because the port won’t open).
consequently, I try to connect via SSH, but it times out.
Then I get to work and try to connect an HDMI monitor, it shows no signal.
The odd part is that if I ping the device from the local network, it responds. The Raspberry Pi is configured with DHCP, and the router reserves the IP address 192.168.1.34 for it. After pinging it, if I run arp -a, I see a row with its MAC address associated with the IP 192.168.1.34. This makes me believe no other device on the network is responding in its place.
A reboot resolves the issue. So far, after a simple restart, all services resume functioning on the first attempt.
This issue mainly occurs at night (or at least I notice it in the morning) and often on holidays (which might just be Murphy’s Law at play).
I have no idea how to debug this problem. I’m looking for help to understand the cause of these "partial freezes" or, alternatively, suggestions for methodologies to collect useful information to identify the issue
EDIT:
Since all the software running on the device (Telegram bot, service for opening the door, etc.) has been developed by me, it’s quite possible that it’s the culprit. For example, if there were a memory leak in one of my applications that caused most of the services to crash, would there be any system logs about it? (Specifically, logs that persist after a reboot.)
EDIT2: Currently, the Raspberry is connected via Wi-Fi (if relevant).
